# Multiple condition update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, concatenation

I know how to update where it is an either/or situation. However, if I need to add more conditions to a statement I am not sure how to proceed.

The desired task is updating 1 to 10, 2 to 20, 3 to 30, 5 to 50, and 0 to 00. Would it be something like such:

```
update table 
set own = (case 
              when own in '1' then '10, 
           case 
              when own in'2' then '20'.....else '00' 
           end);
```

Or would it be best to break it down to five separate update statements where 1, 2,3,5,and 0 are dealt with separately?

Desired Result

```
own     own
 1      10
 2      20
 3      30
 5      50
 0      00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need a single case statement. I used = versus in since you aren't supplying multiple values.

```
update table 
set own=case 
            when own = '1' then '10'
            when own = '2' then '20'
            when own = '3' then '30'
            ....
            else '00' 
        End
```

Comment: good point, i suppose it is a varchar... since they want 0 to 00

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is only to add an '0'

try it:

```
update table set own = RTRIM(LTRIM(own)) + '0';
```

Comment: The answer above resolved it. For some reason, your code resulted in an error about string data would be truncated. Yours seemed quite logical, though.

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It can happen for two reasons; First I didn't use RTIM, LTRIM (Most probably); Second, The Field does not support the new value with one more character. It is only for information; the most important is that you resolved your problem.